Is it anti-pattern using a try-catch block on functional component in React?
I know I should use if-else when branching UI logic. But I'm curious what happens when using a try-catch block in a functional component or render function like below? Is it the anti-pattern?
function SomeScreen() {
  try {
    if (foo) {
      throw Error();
    }
    if (bar) {
      throw Error();
    }
    return <Children />
  } catch (e) {
    return <ErrorComponenet error={e} />
  }
}


The error will bubble up to an error boundary, if you have one. Otherwise, the app will crash (all ui rendered via react will be removed from the screen)

^ that comment above only happens if you throw new Error. try catch is used mostly with async await and is a often turned on as a default typescript rule for that purpose. Outside of async tasks I'd recommend handling errors more gracefully if you can or implement a error boundary in the app as suggested above.

Thanks. I've understood that using try-catch isn't common practice, and ErrorBoundary is a more graceful approach. I have another question: Are there any performance or unexpected behavior problems if I use a try-catch block in the render function? Is it just uncommon usage?

think of it this way. if the error is going to break your UI and is needed for the user to continue then let the error boundary catch it. If a failing part of the script causes a breaking error but isnt actually critical to the end user then quietly try catching it and logging the error is fine. try catch is basically saying there could be a breaking error here but you don't really care to handle it.

React does not see what you are doing in the component. It just executes the body of the component and expects you to return a React Element. It is all that it cares about.
Why would you need a try-catch in the body of the component at first place? If a function might crash, that is the responsibility of the function to handle its errors, you cant always use try catch when using such a function, it is a code smell.
using a try catch in the body of the component would only prevent you from executing invalid code, like trying to access a property of something that does not exist, but still this is not the problem of the component itself to handle such scenarios, it is your problem that you are trying to do something invalid and you should fix that instead of making the component to be silent for errors.
If something is against the react rules and that leads to a crash, you can not prevent that with try-catch, because it is still a valid JS. In that case you have to use ErrorBoundaries
Example:
<div>{ {} }</div>

There is no JS error. You are calling React.createElement('div', null, {}) and there is no JS crash, you can't use try-catch. But it will lead to crash in react-dom, since objects aren't valid elements. The only way to handle that is by ErrorBoundary

for example in a map function you might pull new data on the fly, format or calculate something before displaying it, try catching that is perfectly fine as long as a jsx element or empty string is returned. But in saying that it is usually tidier and more to extract those scenario to methods.

There is another thing, that is not mentioned in the answer, regarding hooks.
You can not call react hooks conditionally, as the docs say:

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns

source
The problem is that using a try catch can cause a conditional call to hooks.
think about something like this (I bet there are better examples...):
const MyComponent = () => {
   let value= 0
   try {
      const [addedValue, setAddedValue] = useState(1);
      value += value
   }
   catch {
   }
   return <div> {value} </div>
}

What you can see in this (a bit weird) example is that try catch can call hooks conditionally, which can cause "undefined behavior" or just plain errors.
